# mongoose is not a function

Tags: javascript, mongoose, nodes

I have this error  TypeError: friendData.insert is not a function
PLS help...
tried changing the methods, the drop works.
I don't know what to do anymore.
I don't know of more write of this problem

```
const FriendSchema = new Schema({
    user: {type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'User'},
    email: {type: String, unique: true, required: true},
    friends: {type: Array},
    subscribe: {type: Array},
    requestFrineds: {type: Array},
})

module.exports = model('Friends', FriendSchema);
```

````
class friendService {
    async addFriend(email, sender) {
        const friendData = await FriendModel.findOne({email: email})
        const senderData = await FriendModel.findOne({email: sender})
        console.log(friendData, senderData)
        await friendData.insert({requestFriends: sender});
        await senderData.insert({subscribe: email});
        friendData.save();
        senderData.save();
        // return friends;
    }```
````

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no `insert` method. If you want to add them to array you can use the `push()` method like so:

```js
class friendService {
    async addFriend(email, sender) {
        const friendData = await FriendModel.findOne({email: email})
        const senderData = await FriendModel.findOne({email: sender})
        console.log(friendData, senderData)
        friendData.requestFriends.push(sender);
        senderData.subscribe.push(email);
        await friendData.save(); //< await the save()
        await senderData.save(); //< await the save()
        // return friends;
    }
```

**Note 1**: you need to `await` the `save()` method too.

There are better ways to achieve this. At the minute you are making 4 calls to the database. Two calls to get `friendData` and `senderData` then another two to update each document with `save()`. If you use [findOneAndUpdate()](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/tutorials/findoneandupdate.html) you could half the number of database requests.

**Note 2**: You also have a typo in your schema `requestFrineds` should be `requestFriends` I presume?

Comment: Maybe you can tell me how to remove the same element from the array.

Comment: Of course. Mongoose has a `pull` method for such cases. `friendData.requestFriends.pull(sender);` or if you have an array of objects then it would be `friendData.requestFriends.pull({key: 'value'});`

Answer (score -1):

I think you mistake between `FriendModel` and `Friends`

The FriendSchema exports as Friends, so you should use like this:

```js
   const friendData = await Friends({email: email})
   const senderData = await Friends.findOne({email: sender})
   console.log(friendData, senderData)
```

and have you imported `Friends` schema yet? Let me know if it works

Comment: `const FriendModel = require('../models/friends-model');
`
I just need to add an element to the array